# Fetch host name from address bar using Java code

Tags: java

I need to retrieve the host name from the address bar using java code. For example, if "www.stackoverflow.com/questions", is there in the address bar, I have to get "www.stackoverflow.com". Please help me.

Comment: Please learn how to [ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), specifically the part about "search, and research"

Comment: look at the URL class.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html

Comment: Thanks pwilmot, the link you have provided explains how to split the url like host name, port etc if we give the url as the argument. My need is to fetch the url itself from the address bar and then split it to get the host name. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please describe the situation where you are facing your problem! Do you want to use applets for your task? Then I think that it might be impossible due to security restrictions, but to give you a meaningful answer we need more information from you. Otherwise the question has to be marked as "not useful"

Comment: Please let me explain. I am writing in 2 comments as the comment size is exeeding.---- Suppose I am invoking a servlet, say "crmdev.com/servlet123"; which is of development instance. Once servlet123 code is execcuted, I redirect it to other page, which is at "crmdev.com/MyHomepage";. In this case, I can directly hard code the latter url(crmdev.com/MyHomepage) in the servlet for redirection which will not work when the same code is deployed in the test environment where the url is like "crmtest.com/servlet123".

Comment: So what I want to do is, to fetch the host name dynamically whether it is "crmdev.com"; or "crmtest.com"; and then append the next page name ("/MyHomePage"), which is common for both the instances. Hope this is clear, please let me know if its not understandable yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you know a bit about format, it can be done very easily with this code :

```
    String http = "www.stackoverflow.com/questions";
    String url = http.substring(0, http.indexOf("/"));

    System.out.println(url);

    http = "http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions";
    String nohttp = http.substring(7, http.length());
    url = nohttp.substring(0, nohttp.indexOf("/"));

    System.out.println(url);
```

---

Or you can use some "nicer" approach with methods :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(getHostname("www.stackoverflow.com/questions"));
    System.out.println(getHostname("http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions"));
}

public static boolean isHttp(String s){
    if (s.indexOf("http://") == 0){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public static String getHostname(String url){
    String nativeUrl = url;
    if (isHttp(nativeUrl)){
        url = url.substring(7);
    }

    url = url.substring(0, url.indexOf("/"));
    if (isHttp(nativeUrl)){
        url = "http://" + url;
    }

    return url;
}
```

**Output**

```
www.stackoverflow.com
http://www.stackoverflow.com
```

Comment: Sorry if my question is not clear. I have to get the url dynamically from the address bar and then split it, instead of having url ready and then split it.

Comment: @user1611498 - are you sure you know what you are doing? If so, then you have to tell us which address bar you use or want to use, how you use it etc.

Comment: yes, please let me explain. I am writing in 2 comments as the comment size is exeeding.----
Suppose I am invoking a servlet, say "http://crmdev.com/servlet123" which is of development instance. Once servlet123 code is execcuted, I redirect it to other page, which is at "http://crmdev.com/MyHomepage". In this case, I can directly hard code the latter url(http://crmdev.com/MyHomepage) in the servlet for redirection which will not work when the same code is deployed in the test environment where the url is like "http://crmtest.com/servlet123".

Comment: So what I want to do is, to fetch the host name dynamically whether it is  "http://crmdev.com"  or "http://crmtest.com" and then append the next page name ("/MyHomePage"), which is common for both the instances. Hope this is clear, please let me know if its not understandable yet.